# How to make sure no errors go uncaught in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I've put try catch blocks in all my REST endpoints, but I'd guess errors could arise else where and if they do I'd like to catch them. How can I make sure no error goes uncaught in my WCF application, where do I catch them? I know you can add error handlers to services but I'm not sure that's the highest layer of the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you cover all (or most of) your endpoints with  try catch blocks you should be good to go!

To take it to the next level, consider using a monitoring tool such as NewRelic:
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/instrumentation/wcf-application-installation

That will monitor more than just errors, it also checks performance of your application over time, that will help you optimise any bottlenecks in your app and server.